# Edit JSON file from a React App - Page Builder Concept

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, architecture, next.js

I need to build a page builder where we want to drag and drop elements to a screen which become a config json object. Then I have to save that config object into a config.json file in the project folder (or somewhere where I can load it when re-rendering the app). We want live reload when editing the pages via this page builder.

The FE drag and drop app is built with React, and I can reach the point where I have the JSON object in memory.

How do you recommend me to do the architecture this for the BE side?

- Is is possible to expose an API endpoint (with Express for example), and save the json file somewhere into the React App "/src" folder? or I can edit only files in "/public" folder?
- What if I refactor my FE React app into a Next.js app? If Next is rendered in the server, does it mean that I can do the config file editing just before it gets rendered?
- Is it better to create an independent Express App where I save all the config.json files? and then exposing them via API endpoints both for editing and reading?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From your question I see that you are developing a app similar to wordpress where the users can easily create a page using drag and drop of elements. So here a configuration is need to persist the placement of elements.

I read all the three approaches mentioned by you and it seem the third approach will help you. You can run a express app and use a db to store the config setting as I find storing it in the file is not a good practice. Once the editing is complete you can make an api call to post the data to db and similarly while reading you can pull the data from db using api call.